# Курсор мыши фонового режима (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, cursor

Существуют различные типы курсоров мыши: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80

Можно ли в JavaFX использовать ***Курсор фонового режима*** (ожидание + стрелка)?

Просмотрев константы класса *javafx.scene.Cursor* я не обнаружил подходящего.

Знаю что можно создать собственный курсор, но можно ли этого избежать ? (например объединить два существующих курсора)

Comment: Исходя из API класса функционала "объеденения" нет. Но и в целом это не стандартное действие, с большим потенциалом на коллизии. Я бы рекомендовал создать свой на основе какого либо ресурса.